# Trying to get a Scheme Depth-First or Breadth-First Search Currying function to work

Tags: search, merge, scheme, currying, depth

I'm new here, and I need help with a function that I'm writing in scheme.

Basically, it involves a search function that can work for either Breadth-First search or Depth-First Search. I think I got the Depth-First-Merge and Breadth-First Merge to work.

However, the problem is to modify the main Search to work as a "currying function" so that when algorithm-specific merge procedures (such as the depth-first-merge or the breadth-first-merge) are passed in as arguments, the search uses that specific type of search. The return

There's two files I have with it. Coins is okay, but search needs fixed. How do I modify the search function here to work as a curried version?

Here's my codes below. first one for search.ss. I made a search2 as an early attempt, but it didn't work. I need to make either search or search2 work as the curried search, (then delete the other). I'm not sure, but I think the merges and two searches are working.

```
;;;
;;; SEARCH:
;;;   -- Non-curried version of generic search algorithm
;;;   -- Can be customized for depth-first and breadth-first search
;;;   -- You must convert it to a curried version so that
;;;      - the function accepts 1 algorithm specific parameter and returns    a function
;;;      - that accepts 3 problem-specific parameters and returns a function
;;;      - that accepths 1 instance specific parameter and performs the search
;;;   -- The 5 parameters are described below
;;;
;;; Input:
;;;   merge-queue
;;;     -- algorithm specific
;;;     -- procedure that takes a list of new paths and a queue
;;;        and returns a new queue
;;;   extend
;;;     -- problem-specific
;;;     -- procedure that takes a state and a list of visited states,
;;;        and returns a list of states that are reachable in one move
;;;        from the given state
;;;   goal?
;;;     -- problem-specific
;;;     -- predicate that takes a state and returns true if the
;;;        state is a goal state, false otherwise
;;;   print-path
;;;     -- problem-specific
;;;     -- procedure that takes a state and prints out a state nicely
;;;   init-state
;;;     -- problem instance-specific
;;;     -- an initial state to start the search from
;;;
;;; OUTPUT:
;;;   -- When succeeded, a path from the initial state to a goal state
;;;   -- When failed, #f
;;;


;;Either this or search2 needs to be rewritten into a curried version
;;To accept either depth-first-merge or breadth-first merge as merge procedures into merge-queue
(define search
  (lambda (merge-queue init-config extend goal?  print-state)
    (letrec
      ((helper
     (lambda (queue)
   (newline)
   (for-each
    (lambda (p) (print-path p print-state))
    queue)
       (cond ((null? queue)  #f)
             ((goal? (caar queue))
      (print-state (caar queue))
      (newline)
      (let ((ans (reverse (car queue))))
        (for-each (lambda (x) (print-state x) (newline)) ans)
        ans))
             (else
              (let ((successors (extend (caar queue))))
        (print-state (caar queue)) (newline)
                (cond ((null? successors)
                       (helper (cdr queue)))
                      (else
           (for-each (lambda (x) (print-state x) (newline))
                 successors)
           (helper
            (merge-queue (cdr queue)
                 (extend-path successors (car queue))))))))))))
  (helper
   (list (list (config->state init-config ))))))



(define search2
  (lambda (merge-queue extend goal? print-path init-state)
(letrec
    ((search-helper
       (lambda (queue visited)
         (cond
           ((null? queue) #f)
           ((goal? (caar queue))
            (begin
              (print-path (car queue))
              (car queue)))
           (else
             (let ((successors (extend (caar queue) visited)))
               (cond
                 ((null? successors)
                  (search-helper (cdr queue) visited))
                 (else
                   (let ((new-paths (extend-path successors (car queue))))
                     (search-helper
          (merge-queue queue new-paths)
          (cond
           (merge-queue))
                       (append successors visited)))))))))))
  (search-helper
    (list (list init-state))   ; initial queue
    (list init-state)))))      ; initial visited


(define extend-path
  (lambda (successors path)
    (if (null? successors)
    '()
    (cons (cons (car successors) path)
      (extend-path (cdr successors) path)))))



;; merge new extended paths to queue for depth first search
;; - uncomment and define your merge for depth first search

(define depth-first-merge
  (lambda (queue paths)
    (append! paths queue)))

;; merge new extended paths to queue for breadth first search
;; - uncomment and define your merge for breadth first search

(define breadth-first-merge
  (lambda (queue paths)
    (append! queue paths)))


;; customize the generic search for depth first search
;; - uncomment and define your depth-first-search in terms of your 
;; curried version of search and depth-first-merge
;; Curry Methods are helpful to this.

(define depth-first-search (search depth-first-merge))
  (lambda (extend goal? print-path)
    (search (depth-first-merge extend goal? print-path))))



;; customize the generic search for breadth first search
;; - uncomment and define your breadth-first-search in terms of your
;;   curried version of search and breadth-first-merge

(define breadth-first-search  (search breadth-first-merge))
  (lambda (extend goal? print-path)
    (search (breadth-first-merge extend goal? print-path))))
```

And this is the Coins file code that is used to compliment the search code. They are in separate files and it loads search.ss (the above one) to work.

```
;; load algorithm specific code for search
(load "search.ss")

;;; Problem specific code for solving the old British coin problems
;;; using the curried version of the simple search procedure. 
;;; The old British coin problem was discussed in the lecture.
;;;
;;; To solve the problem, load this file and run
;;;    (coin-depth-first amount)
;;; or
;;;    (coin-breadth-first amount)
;;; where, amount is replaced with some number, e.g., 48.
;;;
;;; Here, a state is represented as follows:
;;;       (amount (coin1 coin2 ...))
;;;
;;; The car of the state represents how much change you need to pay further.
;;; The cadr of the state represents the combination of coins you used
;;; to pay so far.  For example,
;;;       (48 ())
;;; is the initial state for the amount of 48 cents and
;;;       (0 (24 24)
;;; can be one of the goal states using two 24-cent coins.


;; There are 7 kinds of old British coins
(define old-british-coins '(120 30 24 12 6 3 1))

;; Or, you can do the same for US coins
(define us-coins '(100 50 25 10 5 1))

;; Here, we will do the old British coins
(define *coins* old-british-coins)


;; Is a state the goal state?
(define goal?
  (lambda (state)
    (zero? (car state))))


;; returns children of a state
(define extend
  (lambda (state visited)
    (let ((coins (applicable-coins state visited *coins*)))
    (map
    (lambda (coin)
      (list (- (car state) coin)
        (append (cadr state) (list coin))))
    coins))))


;; find all applicable coins from a state
(define applicable-coins
  (lambda (state visited coins)
   (cond
   ((null? coins) '())
    ((<= (car coins) (car state))
      (if (visited? state visited (car coins))
       (applicable-coins state visited (cdr coins))
       (cons (car coins) (applicable-coins state visited (cdr coins)))))
  (else (applicable-coins state visited (cdr coins))))))


;; see if a state has been visited before
(define visited?
  (lambda (state visited coin)
    (cond
  ((null? visited) #f)
  ((= (- (car state) coin) (caar visited)) #t)
  (else (visited? state (cdr visited) coin)))))


;; pretty-print a state
(define pretty-print-path
  (lambda (path)
    (pretty-print-state (car path))))

(define pretty-print-state
  (lambda (state)
    (let ((change (car state))
      (coins (cadr state))
      (total (apply + (cadr state))))
  (printf
    "===> Total of ~a paid with ~a, with remainder of ~a <===~%"
    total coins change))))


;; customize the generic depth-first-search for coin problem
(define coin-depth-first-search
  (depth-first-search extend goal? pretty-print-path))

;; instance of a coin problem using depth-first search 
(define coin-depth-first
  (lambda (amount)
    (coin-depth-first-search (list amount '()))))



;; customize the generic breadth-first-search for coin problem
(define coin-breadth-first-search
  (breadth-first-search extend goal? pretty-print-path))


;; instance of a coin problem with breadth-first search
(define coin-breadth-first
  (lambda (amount)
    (coin-breadth-first-search (list amount '()))))
```

Can someone please help me? I think all I need to get it to work is to find out how to make the search or search2 code become a curried version.

Answer (score 1):

To curry a function means to redefine it in such a way that it takes a number of parameters less than the current definition and returns a *new* function that takes the rest of the parameters and perform the work of the first one. For instance, you can curry the following two-parameters summing function:

```
(define add 
  (lambda (a b)
    (+ a b)))

(add 7 10)  ;; => 17
```

in the following way:

```
(define add-to
  (lambda (a)
    (lambda (b)
      (+ a b))))

((add-to 7) 10)  ;; => 17

(define add-to-7 (add-to 7))  ;; we give a name to the function that add 7 to its argument

(add-to-7 8)  ;; => 15

(add-to-7 9)  ;; => 16
```

So, to transform the `search2` function (you must extend that function since its last parameter is the problem instance specific one):

```
(define search2
  (lambda (merge-queue extend goal? print-path init-state)
    ...body of search2...
```

as required, you could simply write something like this:

```
(define search2
  (lambda (merge-queue)
    (lambda (extend goal? print-path)
      (lambda (init-state)
        ...body of search2...
```

and then, calling it with the correct number of parameters, you could obtain “partial” functions to be called later. For instance you can define a generic depth first search as:

```
(define depth-first-search (search2 depth-first-merge))
```

then you can define the depth first search specialized for the coin problem, given appropriate definitions for the coin functions:

```
(define coin-depth-first (depth-first-search coin-extend coin-goal? coin-print-path))
```

and finally you can call it with a certain amount to solve the problem:

```
(coin-depth-first 100)
```

Comment: Okay, now I fixed that, but now it's saying when I try it, "Exception, Variable Print-Path is not bound, whenever I try it.

Comment: You have print-state in a function and print-path in a state. Check that you use always the same name.